# Add header to XML array content with XSL Tranx on web pages

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Say if I have the following xml array produced with JAXB to be xslted:

```
<warning>blah</warning>
<warning>blah</warning>
...
```

However I forgot to use a root/parent element to wrap the arrays. So how do I add preceding content to the transformed results of the array, say:

```
Warning:
blah
blah
...
```

Because we have over thousands of xmls I prefer not to marshal them again but get a front-end way out like JS or XSL.

The only solution I can think of is to check if wanring exists in xsl templates. However I've got dozens of templates and warnings can occur basically anywhere in the xml so I prefer not to check of every template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out myself. Simple. CSS pseudo the way to go!

```
.warning:first-child:before{content:"Warning: "}
```